# ElasticSearch 7.x NEST client compatibility with ES 6.x

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, indexing, nest

We have some code that will shortly need to query both ElasticSearch 6.x and 7.x indexes. We are currently using NEST to talk to our ES instances, however from looking on the web it seems that the v6 NEST client does not work when talking to ES 7.x. Obvious answer is to upgrade to v7 of NEST, but I can't find any information on wether the v7 NEST client is backwards compatible.

If we upgrade our NEST client to the version that works with ElasticSearch 7.x, will this client also be able to talk to instances of ElasticSearch 6.x?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find compatibility matrix of the client [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/blob/master/readme.md#compatibility-matrix). It’s likely there are some breaking changes and you won’t be able to work with elasticsearch 6.x when using NEST 7.x.

If you want to work with elasticsearch 7.x you need to install NEST in version [7.0.0beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/7.0.0-beta1).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some breaking changes I noticed:

**NEST 6.8 with ES 7.3.1:**

- There are some serialization errors in the library that you cannot work around, namely with the search API.
- Add Include Types = true parameter to the Mappings API's

**NEST 7.3.1 with ES 6.8**

- The API route for partial document update is different in ES 7 the NEST client doesn't generate the correct route to do updates.
- The Date histogram Interval setting is deprecated but don't fix the warning
- The get mapping response does not deserialize into a usable C# object with properties.

A few days later Elasticsearch release a blog with a how to make it work
 https://www.elastic.co/blog/nest-and-elasticsearch-net-upgrading-your-codebase

Comment: https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/elasticsearch-net is not available anymore, any change in url ?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-7.0.html)

> Elasticsearch 7.0 can read indices created in version 6.0 or above. An Elasticsearch 7.0 node will not start in the presence of indices created in a version of Elasticsearch before 6.0.

Comment: this question is about the NEST client that talks to ES 7, not ES6/7 itself...the docs don't seem to cover that

Comment: But NEST is the client only right? Client communicates with the engine and engine is back compatible. So I think it should word. You always can make a prof of concept to see if it’s gonna work or not.